# Loop in the file name and row number: copying multiple files into one

Tags: vba, excel

I have hundrunds of excel files of which certain parts are to be copied and pasted into another excel file row by row(extracted information from file k are pasted in row k  ). A program has been found to do the task except for the loop part. In the code, the file name and row number are used, e.g :

```
        WorkbookName = "file 1"
        ...
        .Range("C1")=...
```

Can anyone help me with it?

I tried this, which doesn't work :

```
      k=0
      do while k<500
         WorkbookName = "file (1+k)"
         ...
         .Range("C(1+k)")=...
        ...
      Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should put you on the right track.

```
Dim k As Long
Dim WorkbookName As String
Dim thisWbk As Workbook
Dim wbk As Workbook

Set thisWbk = ActiveWorkbook

For k = 0 To 500
    WorkbookName = "file " & CStr(1 + k)
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\mydir\" & WorkbookName & ".xls")

    thisWbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & CStr(1 + k)) _
        = wbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A5")

    wbk.Close
Next k
```

Comment: +1 although slightly concerned about calling a variable `thisWorkbook` when there is the built-in `ThisWorkbook` object already